# Can delays interfere with my timing logic?

Tags: java, timer, calendar, scheduled-tasks

Although i am using the fixedRate method instead of simple schedule does this ensure concretely that no background activity or garbage collection can knock my timing off? Can delays be long enough to make subsequent runs miss the entire window i've given it ? (8:00am to 8:05 am).I've tested executions by changing the OS time and it works but this is first time using scheduling and timing logic.

```
    //1 day
static final long timeDelay = 864000000;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask startBegin = new TimerTask() {    
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);      // 0 to 11
            int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            // March, June, Sept, Dec, First Tues at 8 a.m
            if(((month == 2)||(month == 5)||(month == 8)||(month == 11)) && (dayOfMonth <7) && (hour == 8) && (minute >= 0 && minute <5)) {
                begin();
            }
        } 
    };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(startBegin, 0, timeDelay);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ScheduledExecutorService will do the best it can to run your program at the time specified - however it is limited in doing so by the vagaries of pre-emptive multi-threading, and the limitations of the OS and hardware it is running on.

There are things called "Real Time Operating Systems" that are designed to solve this problem, however for most cases the standard Java behavior will be "good enough". The actual errors are small, with `scheduleAtFixedRate` there are no accumulating errors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Execution within a specific timing window can never be guaranteed, just as network connectivity can never be guaranteed. It's up to you to decide whether that's a serious risk in your environment and what to do about it -- whether to let the timing slip, or skip it and try again in the next window, or whatever.

Comment: Thats concerning because I can't miss an execution as the code runs everyday but executes once quarterly to miss an execution is tragic. Also i'm noticing that for the very first time this codes needs to run exactly at 8 else subsequent runs will be off and i'll never meet my hour condition .. This is messy

Comment: As others have said, you shouldn't accumulate error -- you just can't be certain that it will run precisely at the stated time. If this is critical to you, you can and should manage the rest of your environment such that there won't be conflicts for CPU and network and so on in that time window. Even so, there's always the risk that your machine will have crashed and miss an update for that reason, so if this would really be "tragic" you need to start thinking about hardening the entire environment.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), a timer is a single background thread. Garbage collection can interfere, as can a busy CPU.

If you need more reliable timing, you'll need a real time operating system which supports it.

Answer (score 0):

I would not entrust such an infrequently executed task to a `java.util.Timer` or even a `ScheduledExecutorService`...

I would, rather, use a library such as [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/faq), or set up an external job scheduler like cron on Linux or Windows Task Scheduler, to trigger your cleanup job once a quarter. This would involve far less work on your part, as all the messy edge cases would be handled by the scheduler program/library. Including cases where the machine is unexpectedly power-cycled in the middle of the night, etc. Then you are free to do more productive tasks.